Video overlay of feathered alpha transparency on one edge in Video Sequencer?
I'm attempting to overlay one video clip onto another using a horizontally feathered edge. From what I understand, I need to use a Box Mask, followed by a Blur node, and then apply Alpha Over, as demonstrated in this YouTube Video. But it seems the mask is weird. It's not occupying the area it is supposed to occupy as shown in yellow arrows.

The background is orange so I changed it to white but you can still see a white horizontal line. Also I noticed that this footage gets scaled up when imported in another scene. So for example if I do the compositing in Scene.001 and then in Scene.002 within the Video Sequencer I Add > Scene > Scene.001 and overlap this scene clip on another video I see white overlap when it was not included in the mask and oversized part of the masked area. Where am I going wrong?

I tried again with a new file where this time it occupies the entire width. But it's sort of buggy the positioning of the mask. You can see the mask as white outline yet the masking is wrong. It cannot be moved downward even with Translate node. You can see it gets capped at the bottom straight horizontal line. What is going on?


Thank you to pevinkinel and josh sanfelici for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was that the original video footage loaded into the Movie Clip node was 1920x1080, but I imported the scene into another scene that had a resolution of 540x960. The fix for the horizontal white feathered line was to plug a transparent image with the same dimensions as the original video into the Alpha Over node.


First, to get a clean mask, just disconnect the Image output from the Mask input of the Box Mask node. When in doubt you can always plug your mask into a Viewer node to check what's going on.
Then for the scaling, it's kinda hard to tell what going on in your video sequencer, do you have a file you could share?

Thank you for your help. You're right I forgot to unplug that. I updated my post and you can see the mask is incorrect, it's only masking a small square out of the big square it's supposed to occupy. Then I can see a white horizontal line. It's not transparent even though it is set as transparent in compositor as seen in the Viewer node.

Make sure that your output resolution values are calculated at their 100%.


Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I found the problem, it was because the original video footage loaded into Movie Clip node was 1920x1080 but I imported the scene onto another scene that had 540x960 size. Is there no way to resize it dynamically? Also I still have the horizontal white problem thing, it seems transparency is not applied.

Try plugging the Blur Image Output into the alpha input of a "Set Alpha" node.

I found the solution which was to make a transparent image and then load and plug it into the Alpha Over node. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/324971/142292 What do you think about that solution?
